# Trigger button click from another form

Tags: vb.net

I have a little problem calling the `button1_click` event of `form1` from my `form2`.

When I call `form1.button1_click()` it gives me an error saying:

> `Argument not specified for parameter 'e'.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, try using this:

```
form1.button1_click(Nothing, Nothing)
```

or

```
form1.button1_click(form1.button1, EventArgs.Empty)
```

The error means the procedure you are trying to run has parameters, but you left them out in your call.  The click event is looking for two parameters, `sender As Object` and `e As EventArgs`.

Answer (score 2):

You may also wish to try this:

```
form1.button1.PerformClick()
```

Comment: Looks like it works even if `button1_click` is a private method!